# VSCode wsdl2rest camel extension getting error while generating camel rest dsl from wsdl

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, apache-camel

I am trying to generate camel rest dsl from local wsdl file using wsdl2rest camel extension([related extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=redhat.vscode-wsdl2rest)) into my mavenized project
My **pom.xml** includes required dependencies which is below

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.ws.rs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>${camel.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

I am trying with the extension wizard.After choosing an wsdl file getting an error about initialize velocity engine.

```
Tools can not load the frontend plugin class org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.AntGenerator

Error executing command
org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Tools can not load the frontend plugin class org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.AntGenerator
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getFrontEndGenerators(PluginLoader.java:283)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getFrontEndProfile(PluginLoader.java:393)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.loadFrontEnd(WSDLToJava.java:64)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava.run(WSDLToJava.java:86)
    at org.jboss.fuse.wsdl2rest.impl.codegen.JavaTypeGenerator.execute(JavaTypeGenerator.java:36)
    at org.jboss.fuse.wsdl2rest.impl.Wsdl2Rest.process(Wsdl2Rest.java:92)
    at org.jboss.fuse.wsdl2rest.impl.Main.mainInternal(Main.java:60)
    at org.jboss.fuse.wsdl2rest.impl.Main.main(Main.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.tools.common.ToolException: Failed to initialize velocity engine
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.VelocityGenerator.initVelocity(VelocityGenerator.java:82)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.VelocityGenerator.<init>(VelocityGenerator.java:52)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.AbstractGenerator.<init>(AbstractGenerator.java:47)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.AbstractJAXWSGenerator.<init>(AbstractJAXWSGenerator.java:30)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.frontend.jaxws.generators.AntGenerator.<init>(AntGenerator.java:44)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.core.PluginLoader.getFrontEndGenerators(PluginLoader.java:278)
    ... 16 more
**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeConstants.SpaceGobbling.L�NES**
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeConstants$SpaceGobbling.valueOf(RuntimeConstants.java:298)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.initializeSelfProperties(RuntimeInstance.java:349)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:238)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeInstance.init(RuntimeInstance.java:680)
    at org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeSingleton.init(RuntimeSingleton.java:219)
    at org.apache.velocity.app.Velocity.init(Velocity.java:102)
    at org.apache.cxf.tools.common.VelocityGenerator.initVelocity(VelocityGenerator.java:78)
    ... 26 more
```

Whats the missing point? 
Thanks..

Comment: is it possible to share the wsdl file?
to try to route to correct project, can you try from command-line using this https://github.com/jboss-fuse/wsdl2rest ?
From which IDE are you using the feature? Eclipse desktop? VS Code?

Comment: I'm guessing it's an issue with the wsdl. It gets hung up from time to time. So seeing the wsdl would definitely help us diagnose a bit better.

Comment: Unfortunately i cant share the wsdl because of company policy.@AurélienPupier im using VS Code.

Comment: Actually, in the error log there a line; no enum constant org.apache.velocity.runtime.RuntimeConstants.SpaceGobbling.L�NES
while building it can't find some classes @Fitz

Comment: By the way wsdl is valid, i have implemented in an another project with Apache cxf.The purpose of using wsdl2rest extension is will be able to call this soap service from Quarkus application with rest call

Comment: Glad you found a way to get it to work! Unfortunately, all we're doing is calling the https://github.com/jboss-fuse/wsdl2rest utility under the covers, which uses a subset of the Apache CXF functionality. There are some definite limitations in the way that utility is constructed. If you have suggestions/fixes that can help it support additional wsdls (including yours), we are always looking for contributions. Thanks!